# Create a multiplayer Roguelike game with unity networking

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I'm actually creating a 2D roguelike game with unity, and intend to make a multiplayer mode.
I've already tried to make a shooter like game in multiplayer like in the tutorial on the unity website and it worked well.

But, the unity networking system seem to not be very adapted to make a roguelike game like mine in multiplayer.
For example, all dungeons, monsters, items or characters are created by instantiating them, there's almost nothing initially in the scenes, and with unity networking I'll have to add a Spawn method in addition of the Instantiate one for everything, and add more or less 95% of my prefabs, which represent approximately 300 prefabs, in the network manager.
While I could do it, it will just be very boring, I fear that since unity networking isn't optimized for this kind of game this will be only the first of a dozen other problems of the same kind

So I wanted to ask if you have any suggestions for the creation of a multiplayer roguelike game with unity, like if you have some tips or if it would be better using something else like librairies from the asset store, i'm still a newbie so I don't know wery well all the options

Thank you in advance and sorry for the potential english errors.

Comment: Sorry to be the bearer of bad news but, this isn't a very good question for stackoverflow. It would be better to ask this over on the Unity forums as it's more of an opion-based discussion topic, not Q&A. Good luck finding what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scratch Unity Networking. I would recommend you using Photon Network. From my own experience, PUN is not only easier to work with (than with unity network), but it also works faster, yet pretty universal. Read more on PUN: [here](https://www.photonengine.com/en/PUN)

Good luck!